# Python Flask Intentional Empty Response

Tags: python, flask, response

Is there a way to return a response (from `make_response()` object or similar) with certain properties so that it doesn't render the page again and doesn't do anything else either. I am trying to run a code on the server without generating any output

A simple 'return None' produces:

```
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

This should be possible because the following only downloads a file and doesn't render the template:

```
myString = "First line of a document"
response = make_response(myString)
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=myFile.txt"
return response
```

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You are responding to a request, your HTTP server *must* return *something*. The HTTP 'empty response' response is `204 No Content`:

```
return ('', 204)
```

Note that returning a file to the browser is *not* an empty response, just different from a HTML response.

Comment: Ftr: you may use `httplib.NO_CONTENT` to avoid the magic number.

Comment: Note the equivalent of Python 2’s `httplib.NO_CONTENT` in Python 3 is `http.HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT`.

Comment: @bfontaine: or `http.client.NO_CONTENT`

Comment: @bfontaine: at the bottom of the [`http` package docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html); these *used* to be the normal location until the `HTTPStatus` enum was introduced, see https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e4db76967d7fb0ec0f5a98a9603ca5563f4a8320

Comment: Using `return jsonify(), 204` also works and sets the content type to `application/json` which is generally expected in many API request.

Answer (score 16):

##### Use Flask `Response`

with status 204 (no content)

```
from flask import Response

return Response(status=204)
```